# How do I write the SQL "like CONCAT()" query in sqlachemy?

Tags: mysql, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need the following query in sqlalchemy syntax (value is a column of my_table)

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE "somestring/example" like CONCAT('%',value)
```

I tried this and some more different syntax, but didn't really work

```
query = MyTable.query.filter(MyTable.value.like("somestring/example")).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a filter with `concat()` function, try this :

```
query = MyTable.query.filter(func.concat('%', MyTable.value).like('somestring/example')).all();
```

Comment: I tried this since value, is not defined, but didn't also return the row from the db. 

query = MyTable.query.filter(func.concat('%', MyTable.value).like("somestring/example")).all()

Comment: Can you try `query = MyTable.query.filter(func.concat('%', MyTable.value).like('somestring%')).all()` lets see if it return something

Comment: This one also return an empty list